# Why do the colors I see associated with a particular vibration/sound change?

Tags: synesthesia

After many years of research I found that I am a vibration (sound) to color and feeling synesthete. Everything I have read says that the colors one sees with an associated vibration should be consistent, but this is not the case for me. Anyone know why this would be? My mom, also a synesthete, sees the same colored numbers for each note she plays or hears. I don't see numbers, just colors as clouds that sometimes form patterns. The colors change but they feel similar. For example, the color I see when I hear or play A sharp changes from one moment to the next but the colors stay in the same color family. And most of the colors I see are not truly one color but more of a continuum of a few colors. I have tried to paint the colors but they are almost impossible to create with paint. Any input would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: the reason you have trouble painting the colors is the medium....you might want to try looking at different types of displays to find the purest color that is most easily recreated...like the red blue or green with the most tint of that color...the samsung and apple displays use different kinds of technology...as well as the lg displays in their 4k tv's....you have a chroma recreation problem

Comment: there are glasses called en chroma and hearing aids which might help you tell the colors you see apart as well depending on how your synthesia works....you could use the cool hearing aid test on youtube to isolate the frequencies which make the noises to dissect name and study but i bet you already knew that..

Comment: also if the feeling part becomes an issue tylenol does not act as an antidepressant but numbs feelings so that it might cut down on the synthesia input to your emotions

Comment: doctors of course have access to real medications if you need some help :)